# No text sent to input box using Python

Tags: python, selenium, xpath, inputbox

I am trying to send value to an input box but no matter what I have tried, it does not work.
I have tried the following ways with the [HTML code embedded in this link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zoxPC.png):

```
time.sleep(3)
request_title = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//input[@class='proto-input-text connect-text-input__input-field ng-touched ng-dirty ng-valid']").click()
request_title[0].send_keys('Hello')
```

and

```
time.sleep(3)
request_title = driver.find_element_by_class_name('proto-input-text connect-text-input__input-field ng-touched ng-dirty ng-valid').click()
request_title[0].send_keys('Hello')
```

and

```
time.sleep(3)
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//input[contains(@class, 'proto-input-text connect-text-input__input-field ng-touched ng-dirty ng-valid')]").send_keys('Hello')
```

But all have return the same error - stating that there is "no such element":

```
selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"//input[@class='proto-input-text connect-text-input__input-field ng-touched ng-dirty ng-valid']"}
```

Is there any other configuration to make this work ? ie using CSS or something else ? I am really new into coding and i have no idea how to work on beyond this. I am trying to send "Hello" to an input box, for example.

Comment: Your XPaths seem correct to me. There may be several reasons for this issue. Maybe you have to scroll down a little bit for that element to be clickable by ```Selenium```. Or maybe that element is under an ```iframe``` and you have to switch to it. To detect the issue clearly, we have to see the webpage. Can I kindly remind you to put the url of the webpage to your question?

Comment: I guess it's inside a frame. If that's true then switch frame and try sending text.